# выбрасывает ошибку в android studio

Tags: java

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event. E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback E/MessageQueue-JNI: 

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
   at yaroslav.firstapp.game.Level5$6.onTouch(Level5.java:229)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: yaroslav.firstapp.game, PID: 29572
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
        at yaroslav.firstapp.game.Level5$6.onTouch(Level5.java:229)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

код:
public class Level5 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Dialog dialog;

Dialog dialogEnd;

public int numLeft;

public int numRight;

Array array = new Array();

Random random = new Random();

public int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.universal);

    

    TextView text_levels = findViewById(R.id.text_levels);
    text_levels.setText(R.string.level4);

    final ImageView img_left = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_left);
    img_left.setClipToOutline(true);

    final ImageView img_right = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_right);
    img_right.setClipToOutline(true);

    final TextView text_left = findViewById(R.id.textView_left);
    final TextView text_right = findViewById(R.id.textView_right);

    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

    
    dialog = new Dialog(this); 
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.preview_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    TextView textdescription = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
    textdescription.setText(R.string.text_desription4);

    
    TextView btnclose = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_close);
    btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Level5.this,GameLevels.class);
                startActivity(intent);finish();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
  
    Button button_continue = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_continue);
    button_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
               dialog.dismiss();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    dialogEnd = new Dialog(this); 
    dialogEnd.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogEnd.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_end);
    dialogEnd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogEnd.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialogEnd.setCancelable(false);

    TextView btnclose2 = (TextView)dialogEnd.findViewById(R.id.button_close);
    btnclose2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Level5.this,GameLevels.class);
                startActivity(intent);finish();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            dialogEnd.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Button button_continue2 = (Button)dialogEnd.findViewById(R.id.button_continue);
    button_continue2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Level5.this, Level5.class);
                startActivity(intent);finish();

            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            dialogEnd.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Button button_back =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Level5.this,GameLevels.class);
                startActivity(intent);finish();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    });

    final int[] progress={
        R.id.point1,
            R.id.point2,
            R.id.point3,
            R.id.point4,
            R.id.point5,
            R.id.point6,
            R.id.point7,
            R.id.point8,
            R.id.point9,
            R.id.point10, R.id.point11,R.id.point12,R.id.point13,R.id.point14,R.id.point15,
            R.id.point16,R.id.point17,R.id.point18,R.id.point19,R.id.point20

    };

    final Animation  animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Level5.this, R.anim.alpha);

    numLeft = random.nextInt(10);
    img_left.setImageResource(array.images5[numLeft]);

    text_left.setText(array.text_levels5[numLeft]);

    numRight = random.nextInt(10);

    while (numLeft == numRight){
        numRight = random.nextInt(10);
    }
    img_right.setImageResource(array.images5[numRight]);
  **  text_right.setText(array.text_levels5[numRight]); **

    img_left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                img_right.setEnabled(false);
                if (numLeft>numRight){
                    img_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                }else {
                    img_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                }
            } else if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(numLeft>numRight){
                    if(count<10){
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i<count;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points_green);
                    }
                }else {
                    if(count>0){
                        if (count==1){
                            count=0;
                        }else {
                            count=count-2;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<9;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i<count;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points_green);
                    }
                }
                if (count==10){

                }else {
                    numLeft = random.nextInt(10);
                    img_left.setImageResource(array.images5[numLeft]);
                    img_left.startAnimation(animation);

                    text_left.setText(array.text_levels5[numLeft]);

                    numRight = random.nextInt(10);

                    while (numLeft == numRight){
                        numRight = random.nextInt(10);
                    }
                    img_right.setImageResource(array.images5[numRight]);
                    img_right.startAnimation(animation);
                    text_right.setText(array.text_levels5[numRight]);

                    img_right.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    img_right.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                img_left.setEnabled(false);
                if (numLeft<numRight){
                    img_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                }else {
                    img_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                }
            } else if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(numLeft<numRight){
                    if(count<10){
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i<count;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points_green);
                    }
                }else {
                    if(count>0){
                        if (count==1){
                            count=0;
                        }else {
                            count=count-2;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<9;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i<count;i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_points_green);
                    }
                }
                if (count==10){

                }else {
                    numLeft = random.nextInt(10);
                    img_left.setImageResource(array.images5[numLeft]);
                    img_left.startAnimation(animation);

                    text_left.setText(array.text_levels5[numLeft]);

                    numRight = random.nextInt(10);

                    while (numLeft == numRight){
                        numRight = random.nextInt(10);
                    }
                    img_right.setImageResource(array.images5[numRight]);
                    img_right.startAnimation(animation);
                    text_right.setText(array.text_levels5[numRight]);

                    img_left.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
массив:
    final int[] images5={
            R.drawable.dalglish,
            R.drawable.baia,
            R.drawable.ibrahimovic,
            R.drawable.xavi,
            R.drawable.giggs,
            R.drawable.pique,
            R.drawable.messi,
            R.drawable.iniesta,
            R.drawable.max,
            R.drawable.alves,
    };

    final int[] text_levels5={
            R.string.level5_1,
            R.string.level5_2,
            R.string.level5_3,
            R.string.level5_5,
            R.string.level5_6,
            R.string.level5_7,
            R.string.level5_8,
            R.string.level5_9,
            R.string.level5_10,
    };
```

Comment: читай ошибку, гугли, что означает это исключение

Comment: Где исходный код? Учитесь самостоятельно искать ответы

Comment: если бы я не искал этот вопрос в гугле я бы сюда не писал, какой код тебе нужно? @ArtyMorris

Comment: Плохо искали. Очень плохо искали. Вы пытались работать с массивами, и получили эту ошибку. Это из названия ошибки понятно. А почему она возникла, и где, без вашего кода не узнать

Comment: @ArtyMorris 
это первый мой андроид проект, и моих знаний не достаточно чтобы справиться самому

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException это название ошибки. Его вбиваете в поиск и читаете что означает. И так с любой другой ошибкой. Укажите строчку, где ошибка возникает

Comment: @ArtyMorris указал

Comment: Если я решил вашу проблему, поставьте знак, что проблема решена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массивы в ЯП нумеруются обычно с 0. То есть ваш массив, text_levels5, имеет индексы от 0 до 8. Это 9 элементов. Вы генерируете числа от 0 до 9. Естественно, в массиве индекса 9 у вас нет. Поэтому и ошибка. Генерируйте числа от 0 до 8.

В процессе работы с массивами, для избежания таких ошибок, используйте text_levels5.lenght, это вернёт длину массива.